# Смена отпечатка браузера (аппаратный отпечаток) в Selenium

Tags: c#, веб-программирование, selenium

Сайты различных типов могут собирать информацию типа

- Canvas hash;
- WebGL hash;
- AudioContext hash;
- Font hash.

Можно ли изменить в `Selenium` их значения?

Искал свойства в `ChromeOptions`, но ничего нужного не нашел. Как вариант возможно есть какая-то "оболочка" с под которой можно запустить код, в которой можно указывать различные системные характеристики?

Так же видел способы смены через расширения, но они мне не особо подходят.

Главная цель - создать "видимость" работы с разных устройств.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Selenium это не браузер, а драйвер браузера. Какого именно - выбираете вы сами. Если кратко, не можете. Я даже не уверен, что заголовок `User-Agent` сможете поменять, а это вообще самый поверхностный и явный показатель этого самого отпечатка.

Comment: User-Agent уже менял, но мне этого недостаточно

Answer (score 2):

1. создаешь отдельный профиль необходимого браузера(для каждого браузера без проблем находишь инструкцию как это сделать)
2. перелогиниваешся в этот профиль браузера
3. устанавливаешь плагины которые стирают отпечаток браузера. Ghostery кажется частично это делает, но не полностью. Privacy Badger еще весьма неплох, но его нужно обучать вручную под потребности... Собственно плагины ищи по запросу `%браузер% remove fingerprint addon` . Кстате в фаярфоксе в родных настройках есть блокировка фингерпринта -  но я не знаю на сколько хорошо она работает.
4. Проверяешь на сколько успешно это вышло (есть специальные сайты для проверки этого) например на https://amiunique.org/fp или на https://coveryourtracks.eff.org/ хотя лучше проверить на десятке разных сайтов
5. в селениуме подключаешся именно к этому браузеру и используя именно этот профиль браузера

Вуаля

Когда найдешь что-то стоящее - поделись информацией здесь какие конкретно плагины дали хороший результат